# Odoo 13 hide delete button from all forms

Tags: odoo

Is there any module that has this functionallity?

I want to hide the delete button, so that only the users that are part of an specific group can see the delete option.

There is an OCA module that does this, but for the Export button

Thanks beforehands

Comment: https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/12.0/rp_hide_action_form_v12/ refer this

Answer (score 1):

Odoo 13 hide delete button from all forms
add attribute all of tags tree and form in xml

```
 <tree delete="1" >
 <tree string="Users" delete="false">
 <form  delete="false">
```